# Twitter Integration on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I want to integrate Twitter in my iPhone App for getting some tweets of a particular twitter account. Please suggest me the best idea to do that ?

**NOTE:**

> 1. I just want to show the tweets from a particular account. Any short
>    method will be help full rather than full twitter integration
> 2. For now I am using RSS to get the tweets but somewhere I've heard
>    that RSS twitter feeds are very unreliable and they are going to stop
>    support for RSS soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer.
- I added MGTwitterEngine into my project.

Here is the code :**[MyViewController's -(void)viewDidLoad]**-

```
MGTwitterEngine *twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[twitterEngine getUserTimelineFor:username sinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:10];
```

If you guys need some more clarification feel free to ask. I'll try to help you out as much as I can.

Regards!!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a full implementation, you just need to perform a query to the statuses of the specific user
For example, to get the last 20 tweet from charliesheen with ASIHTTPRequest

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/charliesheen.xml"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
// this is called if the request is successful
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
// this is called if the request fails
}
```

If don't want to use xml, just change it to json

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/charliesheen.json
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth/tree/27a8631a5e32c36ea40d532c8343fafe7cc5e95c
And download the source project..

This links provide you last five tweets..